# Unable to deploy Spring application in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy PetClinic(Spring application) in App Engine. I have added plugins and dependencies.

```
*<plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
      </plugin>*

 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It is running while I ran locally using *./mvnw -DskipTests appengine:run*. However, it did not deploy to App Engine when I ran */mvnw -DskipTests appengine:deploy*. I'm getting an error related to BeanCreationexception   (**Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource**). How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going through the code lab tutorial for deploying a Spring boot application to app engine?

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html

Also this github repository will be a useful reference:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

As for your specific error. I would investigate which dependencies are bringing in the `entitymanager`, and what you may be missing. Starting with exactly what is causing the creation exception.